# Elasticsearch 7.17.8 параметр thread_pool.bulk.queue_size

Tags: elasticsearch

Как и на основании чего расчитывается параметр thread_pool.bulk.queue_size в elasticsearch 7.17.8, если он не задан в конфигурационном файле?

По документации найти не удалось